# Google analytics report more then one screen from one activity

Tags: android, google-analytics

How can I report more than one screen from my main activity? I have one activity in which I have view flipper and when I flip from one to another view I want to report which view I see now?

I tried like that:

```
private List<Tracker> trackers;
```

Then fro every view i do

```
Tracker tracker=mGaInstance.getTracker("UA-mynumver-"+id_viewa);
```

And when I load one view I report it like that:

```
trackers.get(0).sendView("name_of_view");
```

I also have easy tracker like that:

```
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);      
}

@Override
  public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution I shouldn't use multiple trackers i need jsut one, adn always when i open new view just do

```
tracker.sendView("name_of_view");
```